# Trying to handle window.onpopstate function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hadle how to work with `window.onpopstate`. I thought that it must hadle browsers `back` and `forward` buttons but it also handles any links... So why does it happen?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>

    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.onpopstate = function( e ) {
            console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <a href="#1">first</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#2">second</a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because that is what is supposed to happen.

> The `popstate` event is fired when the active history entry changes.

— [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate)

> Fired at the Window when the user navigates the session history

— [HTML 5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-popstate)

Comment: hm... is the an event which fired only when browsers back and forward buttons pressed ?